# C++: Why does this speed my code up?

Tags: c++, performance, gcc

I have the following function

```
double single_channel_add(int patch_top_left_row, int patch_top_left_col, 
        int image_hash_key, 
        Mat* preloaded_images,
        int* random_values){

    int first_pixel_row = patch_top_left_row + random_values[0];
    int first_pixel_col = patch_top_left_col + random_values[1];
    int second_pixel_row = patch_top_left_row + random_values[2];
    int second_pixel_col = patch_top_left_col + random_values[3];

    int channel = random_values[4];

    Vec3b* first_pixel_bgr = preloaded_images[image_hash_key].ptr<Vec3b>(first_pixel_row, first_pixel_col);
    Vec3b* second_pixel_bgr = preloaded_images[image_hash_key].ptr<Vec3b>(second_pixel_row, second_pixel_col);

    return (*first_pixel_bgr)[channel] + (*second_pixel_bgr)[channel];
}
```

Which is called about one and a half million times with different values for `patch_top_left_row` and `patch_top_left_col`. This takes about 2 seconds to run, now when I change the calculation of first_pixel_row etc to not use the arguments but hard coded numbers instead (shown below), the thing runs sub second and I don't know why. Is the compiler doing something smart here ( I am using gcc cross compiler)?

```
double single_channel_add(int patch_top_left_row, int patch_top_left_col, 
        int image_hash_key, 
        Mat* preloaded_images,
        int* random_values){

        int first_pixel_row = 5 + random_values[0];
        int first_pixel_col = 6 + random_values[1];
        int second_pixel_row = 8 + random_values[2];
        int second_pixel_col = 10 + random_values[3];
            int channel = random_values[4];

    Vec3b* first_pixel_bgr = preloaded_images[image_hash_key].ptr<Vec3b>(first_pixel_row, first_pixel_col);
    Vec3b* second_pixel_bgr = preloaded_images[image_hash_key].ptr<Vec3b>(second_pixel_row, second_pixel_col);

    return (*first_pixel_bgr)[channel] + (*second_pixel_bgr)[channel];
}
```

EDIT:

I have pasted the assembly from the two versions of the function
using arguments: http://pastebin.com/tpCi8c0F
using constants: http://pastebin.com/bV0d7QH7

EDIT:

After compiling with -O3 I get the following clock ticks and speeds:

using arguments: 1990000 ticks and 1.99seconds 
using constants: 330000 ticks and 0.33seconds

EDIT: 
using argumenst with -03 compilation: http://pastebin.com/fW2HCnHc
using constant with -03 compilation: http://pastebin.com/FHs68Agi

Comment: `gcc` has command-line options which can be used to view assembly language output. Why don't you get the assembly for both of the code snippets you show here, `diff` them, and post the resulting diff in your question?

Comment: You couldn't reproduce this as a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), could you?

Comment: Look at the assembly code generated. In the second case maybe the compiler uses some SSE instructions. Also, the two implementations don't seem to do the same thing.

Comment: Why are the values in the second example 5, 6, 8, and 10 when in order to replicate the first example they should be 5, 6, 5, 6? Not that I think that's the source of the speedup. But I'm curious.

Comment: @Omnifarious Indeed, I am not trying to replicate the first example, just trying to find out why using constants vs the function arguments are making such a difference in execution speed

Comment: What does the calling code look like? How much effort is spent on evaluating the arguments? Are you calling it with constant values as arguments?

Comment: @AndreyT no, the arguments are evaluated at runtime (in both tests)

Comment: Are you calling it with the exact same values each time, other than the `patch_foo` args? If so, a clever optimizer (or a JIT, if you're doing C++.NET or something) might be able to figure out that the second one has constant effects and doesn't need to be called N times at all.

Comment: @AlexD I am working on getting the assembly output, eclipse seems to not allow me to direct build output to file

Comment: @abarnert different values each time (the patch moves)

Comment: Just copy the command line that eclipse is triggering to compile this file, and run that same command line in bash/cmd/whatever yourself, with the appropriate extra argument for whichever compiler you're using.

Comment: I understand that the `patch_foo` arguments are different each time—which would affect the first version, but not the second. The question is whether the _other_ arguments (such as the `random_values` array) are the same each time—which would affect both.

Comment: @abarnert yes random_values and the preloaded_images and in fact image_hash_key are the same on every call

Comment: Did you use optimization?  Compile with `-O1` or higher before timing your code; the performance of unoptimized code is highly variable and uninteresting....

Comment: @AlexD I have pasted the assembly

Comment: @ChrisDodd I will try that now

Comment: We also need the assembly for the code that calls this function in a loop. It's possible that the function call gets inlined, and therefore the code you just showed us never gets run…

Comment: You are most likely gonna need to provide an SSCCE to get any meaningful answer from us.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I have compiled with -O3 and for the argument version it takes 1.99 seconds and for the constant version it takes 0.33 seconds

Comment: The assembly looks far too sane to have been generated by the optimizer. Are you sure the assembly reflects what you get when you compile with `-O3`?

Comment: @Omnifarious no the assembly was posted before the -O3 compilation, I can recompile and post but I think there are calls for a SSCCE

Comment: @Aly: I'm not ready to give up on the code example and the assembly after `-O3` yet. :-) But yes, an SSCCE would probably help a lot. :-)

Comment: @Omnifarious working on it, would you like the -O3 compiled code?

Comment: @Aly: The assembly in both the constant and non-constant cases with `-O3` would indeed be helpful.

Comment: Yes, post the -O3 code, and again, also post the calling code, not just the functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the x86 platform there are instructions that very quickly add small integers to a register. These instructions are the `lea` (aka 'load effective address') instructions and they are meant for computing address offsets for structures and the like. The small integer being added is actually part of the instruction. Smart compilers know that these instructions are very quick and use them for addition even when addresses are not involved.

I bet if you changed the constants to some random value that was at least 24 bits long that you would see much of the speedup disappear.

Secondly those constants are known values. The compiler can do a lot to arrange for those values to end up in a register in the most efficient way possible. With an argument, unless the argument is passed in a register (and I think your function has too many arguments for that calling convention to be used) the compiler has no choice but to fetch the number from memory using a stack offset load instruction. That isn't a particularly slow instruction or anything, but with constants the compiler is free to do something much faster than may involve simply fetching the number from the instruction itself. The `lea` instructions are simply the most extreme example of this.

**Edit: Now that you've pasted the assembly things are much clearer**

In the non-constant code, here is how the add is done:

```
addl    -68(%rbp), %eax
```

This fetches a value from the stack an offset `-68(%rpb)` and adds it to the `%eax%` register.

In the constant code, here is how the add is done:

```
addl    $5, %eax
```

and if you look at the actual numbers, you see this:

```
0138 83C005
```

It's pretty clear that the constant being added is encoded directly into the instruction as a small value. This is going to be much faster to fetch than fetching a value from a stack offset for a number of reasons. First it's smaller. Secondly, it's part of an instruction stream with no branches. So it will be pre-fetched and pipelined with no possibility for cache stalls of any kind.

So while my surmise about the `lea` instruction wasn't correct, I was still on the right track. The constant version uses a small instruction specifically oriented towards adding a small integer to a register. The non-constant version has to fetch an integer that may be of indeterminate size (so it has to fetch ALL the bits, not just the low ones) from a stack offset (which adds in an additional add to compute the actual address from the offset and stack base address).

**Edit 2: Now that you've posted the `-O3` results**

Well, it's much more confusing now. It's apparently inlined the function in question and it jumps around a whole ton between the code for the inlined function and the code for the calling function. I'm going to need to see the original code for the whole file to make a proper analysis.

But what I strongly suspect is happening now is that the unpredictability of the values retrieved from `get_random_number_in_range` is severely limiting the optimization options available to the compiler. In fact, it looks like in the constant version it doesn't even bother to call `get_random_number_in_range` because the value is tossed out and never used.

---

I'm assuming that the values of `patch_top_left_row` and `patch_top_left_col` are generated in a loop somewhere. I would push this loop into this function. If the compiler knows the values are generated as part of a loop, there are a very large number of optimization options open to it. In the extreme case it could use some of the SIMD instructions that are part of the various SSE or 3dnow! instruction suites to make things a whole ton faster than even the version you have that uses constants.

The other option would be to make this function inline, which would hint to the compiler that it should try inserting it into the loop in which it's called. If the compiler takes the hint (this function is a bit largish, so the compiler might not) it will have much the same effect as if you'd stuffed the loop into the function.

Comment: If you look at the assembly he posted, the compiler is not using `lea` with a constant offset, it's explicitly adding the constants to the variables, then using the variables as offsets in `mov` instructions.

Comment: @abarnert: Yep. I edited my answer to reflect my mistaken assumption.

Comment: @Omnifarious I see, I have inlined the function and compiled with -03 and still seeing large difference in time (I have edited the question). The constant version takes 0.33 secs and the non constant 1.99 - even if it fetches values from the stack surely this it too large a time difference?

Comment: @Aly: Are you sure the assembly you posted is the result of compiling with `-O3`?

Comment: @Aly: Also, the assembly you showed just stuffs the values into locations on the stack after they're generated in both the constant case and the non-constant case. That means the code following can't really be substantially different in either case. So, in the case of the assembly you posted, the only difference is the one I outlined.

Comment: @Aly: After the `-O3` my analysis remains basically the same.

Comment: @Aly: Actually, I take that back. As I expected `-O3` muddied the waters considerably. Can you post the original code for the whole file, not just the one function?

Comment: @Aly: I just realized the constant version doesn't even appear to be called `get_random_number_in_range` because the return value is never used.

Answer (score 2):

Well, binary arithmetic operations of `immediate constant vs. memory` format are expected to produce faster code than the ones of `memory vs. memory` format, but the timing effect you observe appears to be too extreme, especially considering that there are other operations inside that function.

Could it be that the compiler decided to inline your function? Inlining would allow the compiler to easily eliminate everything related to the unused `patch_top_left_row` and `patch_top_left_col` parameters in the second version, including any steps that prepare/calculate these parameters in the calling code.

Technically, this can be done even if the function is not inlined, but it is generally more complicated.